# poll an Http endpoint till a condition has been satisfied

Tags: mule

I would like to poll an HTTP endpoint (every 5 secs), till I get response status message as "completed". How can I accomplish this? I am aware of the quartz polling module, whereby one can poll after a repeated time-period. But not sure how can I add a stop condition to it.
Is there any mechanism of self-loop?

I have tried until-successful component:-

```
<until-successful failureExpression="#[json:status != 'COMPLETED']" maxRetries="5" secondsBetweenRetries="10" synchronous="true">
```

But its giving my exception

Answer (score 1):

The Until Successful Scope is probably what you want: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope

Comment: Can I add a condition?  I get a JSON response giving status, I can only move ahead if the status is COMPLETED, otherwise keep re-pinging the HTTP endpoint

Comment: I have tried - <until-successful failureExpression="#[json:status != 'COMPLETED']" maxRetries="5" secondsBetweenRetries="10" synchronous="true">. It gives an error